# Is hard thresholding operator Lipschitz?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, lipschitz-functions

A Hard thresholding operator $H_k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as a vector-valued function that maintains the top-k entries of a given vector in an absolute value sense and zero out the rest. As an example $H_2(x)=[-5,0,-3,0]^{\top}$ where $x=[-5,2,-3,1]^{\top}$ and $k=2$. (In a case where two entries are equal we keep the value with smallest index)

**Question**: Is $H_k$ a Lipschitz function that satisfies the following:

$$
||H_k(x)-H_k(y)||_2 \leq c ||x-y||_2 \quad \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

Comment: Define $x$ to be equal to $1+1/n$ at the first $\min(k,n/2)$ components and $1-1/n$ at the last $\min(k,n/2)$ components and $0$ in any other component that might be left over. Define $y$ the same way, but swapping the roles of $1+1/n$ and $1-1/n$. Then $H_k(x)$ is going to keep the first $\min(k,n)$ components of $n$ and $H_k(y)$ the last $\min(k,n)$ components of $y$ and zero the rest. This will cause $\|H_k(x)-H(y)\|_2$ to stay larger than $1$, while $\|x-y\|_2$ can be made as small as you want by letting $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Consider $x=(1, 1-\epsilon)$, $y=(1-\epsilon,1)$ and $k=1$. We have $H(x)=(1,0)$ and $H(y) = (0,1)$, but $||x-y||=O(\epsilon)$

Comment: @Urtur: Would be possible to have any condition to make it happen?

Comment: @Nick Alger: Is there any circumstances that I can get it right? Can I put some restrictions on x and y and make it happen? Restrict them into a specific ball so that I get a local version?

Comment: It is not even continuous.

Comment: @Sepide It should be continuous on a region where the entries in the vector never "cross over" each other. E.g., let $x$ be a vector with distinct entries, and let $r$ be the smallest gap between entries in $x$. Then it should be continuous on the open ball $B_r(x)$. On this set it is just a projection onto a fixed basis.

Comment: @Nick Alger: but this is very hard to satisfy:) It is still hard for me to grasp it and characterize what you mentioned? is there any way that can make it easier to satisfy? I have posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189883/how-to-simplify-the-difference-between-hard-thresholded-points-that-are-very-clo) with bounty, can you please take a look and see if you can solve it?

Comment: @Sepide With regards to your other question, I'm not sure. You could write a short computer program to draw many random vectors and compute the expected value in the formula, then explore how it depends on $n, k$, and $\sigma$ numerically, and see if any patterns emerge. Then if there is a clear pattern you could try to prove it.